# Mimicking click once behavior

Tags: .net, vb.net, installation, clickonce

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, a ClickOnce application is being run directly off of a webpage to be installed.  Is there a way to mimic this ability?  I plan on making my own installer but I want installing the software to be as easy and fast as possible (my software is aimed towards teens and older children).  Does anybody have any ideas?  I'm using vb.net so any .net examples are appreciated.

Thanks if you can!  I don't, however, need people to tell me alternate methods than the one proposed.  This is the way I'm doing it and how it needs to be :)

Basically, once you click on a link in a browser, a similar dialog will pop-up asking (instead of saying "Install // Don't Install") if you would like to run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so...

The dialog you see is not a dialog the application provides but a dialog that the .NET framework supplies for a ClickOnce application installer.

You could do a similar thing if you force your users to first install your own application installer, that would register some protocol as its own and be a server that responds to protocol requests.

something like

myinstaller://http%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite%2Ecom%2Fapp%2Eexe

And then respond to this, download the exe and run it...

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  Thanks :)  I'll mark it as answered in 4 minutes.  For now, please except this vote.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to accomplish this with a [smart client](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DotNetBuildSmClnts.aspx).  I confess that I have done nothing more than read about them, so I apologize if I have steered you in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

For obvious security reasons, there's no way to tell a browser to download and run an executable without the use of some bootstrapping technology like ClickOnce or Java. Even in those cases, the dialog you refer to cannot be circumvented: the bootstrapper will always confirm with the user before running the software.

Answer (score 1):

can I just ask why not use ClickOnce? Is it simply the Install/Don't Install phrasing you don't like. I believe it is possible to alter the ClickOnce UI, so you could just use ClickOnce and customise the install process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx.

Cheers,
Greg